# Keytool gives wrong android apk hashcode

Tags: java, android, cmd, hashcode, keytool

I'm trying to get an apk hashcode using keytool. This tool seems to give me wrong hashcode when my alias has white space in it. The command then looks like this:

`C:\OpenSSL\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -export -alias "my alias" -keystore C:
\key\keystore | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl enc
-a -e`

Am I passing this argument correctly?

The easiest solution would be changing alias, but unfortunately app is already in google play and I can't touch its keystore.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the hash is wrong? The alias has nothing to do with this, it just points to a certificate. Export to a file and check each step instead of using pipes to confirm.

BTW, this will Base64 encode the binary value of the hash. Are you sure that is what you need?